# Getting illegal argument exception while using CacheDir for Screenshot

Tags: java, android, file-handling

Hello everyone i have an application in which i have a toolbar with share icon and when i click the share icon it takes the screenshot with a tiny url but the problem is that now i am getting illegal argument exception which was working fine.
Here is the exception

***java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/com.ct.app/cache/screenShot.png***

I debuged my code followed some questions on SO for same but still not able to solve it.
I would appreciate any help thanks.
Here is the code for Screenshot

```
public void createScreenShot(View v)
    {
        try {
            RelativeLayout rootview = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.photoScreen);
            rootview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            rootview.buildDrawingCache(true);
            Bitmap bitmap = rootview.getDrawingCache(true).copy(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565, false);
            rootview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
            File file = new File(this.getCacheDir(), "screenShot" + ".png");
            Log.e("filelocation",file.toString());
            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
            Log.e("fileoutput",fOut.toString());
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close();
            file.setReadable(true, false);
            FileOutputStream out = null;
            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("text/plain");
            share.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Download Android App");
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,"com.ct.app.provider",file));
            share.setType("image/*");
            share.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"),20);

        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Here is the menifest provider

```
 <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="@string/file_provider_authority"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_provide" />
        </provider>
```

and here is the file provide.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <cache-path name="cache" path="/images/" />
    <files-path name="files" path="/images/" />
    <external-files-path name="external_files" path="."/>
    <!--<external-cache-path name="external_files" path="." />-->
</paths>
```

Comment: `path="/images/"`. Change to `path="."`.

Comment: Thank you @greenapps this was a great help..